# css not working on BarcodeScanner User Interface

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, html, barcode

I want to customize font-family on BarcodeScanner User Interface but it appears css is not applied.
As a sample code is provided on [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_barcodescanner_example_kiosk) and [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_barcodescanner_ui), I used and modified it, directly added style attribute on h2 and h3 tag like;

```html
    <!-- Custom UI for the scanner is defined here. We set display:none here because the scanner will show this. -->
    <div data-id="BarcodeScannerCustomUI" style="display: none;">
        <div class="qr-reader-section">
            <h1 align="right"><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="nimbusbarcodescanner://dismiss">✖</a></h1>
            <h2 align="center" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue;">Welcome, let's get you verified!</h2>
            <h3 align="center" style="font-family: Helvetica Neue;">Point the front side of your Health Card<br>at the camera on this device.</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

but this is not working as expected.

So I created css file under the same component folder and pointed as

```css
.qr-reader-section h2 h3 {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
}
```

but still no luck. Anything has changed.

Or do I have to modify this section on JavaScript?

```js
        if (this.sessionScanner != null && this.sessionScanner.isAvailable()) {
            let elem = this.template.querySelector('div[data-id=BarcodeScannerCustomUI]');
            let backgroundViewHTML = '<header><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"></header>';
            backgroundViewHTML += `<html><body>${elem.innerHTML}</body></html>`;

            // Specify the size of the scanner camera view, use of the front-facing camera, and pull in the custom UI defined above
            const scanningOptions = {
                "barcodeTypes": [this.sessionScanner.barcodeTypes.QR],
                "scannerSize": "XLARGE",
                "cameraFacing": "FRONT",
                "showSuccessCheckMark": true,
                "presentWithAnimation": false,
                "backgroundViewHTML": backgroundViewHTML
            };
            // ...
        }
```

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Apparently, an iframe is being created to isolate the HTML from the main page. You would want to use `style="whatever: here"` rather than `class="whatever here"`, because your styles won't transfer to the iframe.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! 
I think this was just my bad, it worked as just add `style="color: red;"` on h2, h3 tag directly! Or you can add variable that is included `<style>` tag onto `elem.innerHTML` on JavaScript side.